# Deklination relativer Sätze

Tags: relative-pronoun, declension, attribute

Gegeben sei folgender Satz:

> Das ist das Handy, das ich gekauft habe.

Ich würde gerne den Relativsatz – *das ich gekauft habe* – als ein Attribut verwenden. Was wäre dann richtig?

> Das ich gekaufte Handy?

oder

> Das von mir gekaufte Handy?

Wie würde man seine Antwort begründen? Vielen Dank im Voraus!

Answer (score 1):

Das Partizip II kann zwar als Attribut verwendet werden. Das hat aber nichts mehr mit einem Relativsatz zu tun.

Vielmehr gelten die Regeln des Passivs, genauer des *Zustandspassivs*. Aus dem Subjekt des Aktivs wird *von* + Dativ.

Daher ist nur folgendes korrekt:

> Das von mir gekaufte Handy ...

Der Satzanfang "Die Aufgabe, die ich bekommen habe, ..." kann nicht analog umgeformt werden, weil das Verb *bekommen* nicht passivfähig ist. Daher muss es durch ein anderes Verb ersetzt werden: "Die mir zugewiesene/gestellte Aufgabe ..."

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort. Wie würden Sie nun den Satz "das ist die Aufgabe, die ich bekommen habe." umformen?